# Reference data in another worksheet based on a qualifier

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to reference data in another worksheet based off of a qualifier on the first...

```
Sheet 1, A1 = Age of Store (months)
Sheet 1, B1 = New Sales projections (Reference Sheet 2, D1 information here based off of month number in column A)
```

Based upon the age of the store (months), I need it to reference the data in sheet 2 and the cooresponding column.

```
Sheet 2, A1 = Month 1, projected numbers
Sheet 2, B1 = Month 2, projected numbers
Sheet 2, C1 = Month 3, projected numbers
Sheet 2, D1 = Month 4, projected numbers
```

Etc.

Answer (score 1):

In Sheet1's B1:

```
=INDEX('Sheet2'!1:1,,A1)
```

This returns an entry in a column given in `A1` in row 1 (`1:1`) of `Sheet2`. The syntax of `INDEX` is `INDEX(<array>,<row>,[<col>])`.

Comment: @user2730386: Consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764) if it solved your problem.